# archivedObject(ofClass:from:) treats [SCNNode] differently that SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift5

I have two methods, one to unarchive a root `SCNNode`, the other to unarchive an array of root `SCNNode`'s (within a single file).
This code for the solo node works:

```
guard let component = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: SCNNode.self, from: moleData)
    else {
        component = failNode
        return component    // return to moleFunc to abort?
    }
```

But when I try to retrieve an array of nodes, it doesn't work:

```
 guard let components = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: [SCNNode].self, from: moleData)
     else {
         components = []
         return components    // return to moleFunc to abort?
     }
```

In the above, `unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)` two errors:
*Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[SCNNode]' conform to 'NSCoding'*  and *Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[SCNNode]' inherit from 'NSObject'*.

The form below will run OK but the operation fails to extract a useable array of nodes:

```
    guard let components = try? (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: moleData) as! [SCNNode])
         else {
print("unarchivedObject(ofClass: FAIL, components = ", components)
             components = []
             return components    // return to moleFunc to abort
         }
```

The `print`, within the else, prints out as "[<SCNNode: 0x600001973600 | no child>]", the debugger shows zero elements.

The salient line from the Swift 3 implementation, which worked just fine, is:

```
components = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? [SCNNode])!
```

The node files all reside in the Bundle as plists.

I've no idea how to make the array version "conform" whereas the single SCNNode does just fine.

Comment: You say that `let components = try? (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: moleData) as! [SCNNode])` "gets rid of the errors but fails in returning a proper value." Can you explain what you mean by that? That was quite a clever bit of code; in what way did it fail?

Comment: This isn't a bazaar. There's no haggling. Nor is it a help desk. It's a crowd sourced encyclopedia.

Comment: Your code has no guard statement.

Comment: Yes, it says you omitted the guard. But I stand by what I said. The code as shown has no guard statement. If you want help with your real code show your real code, not your guess at what the good parts would be.

Comment: What I asked you was what went wrong with `let components = try? (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: moleData) as! [SCNNode])`. That doesn't even appear in the code you're showing now.

Comment: I use the singular `component` in the first, working, method. The plural `components` its used in the second method retrieving the `[SCNNode]`. When I used `[SCNNode]` in the deprecated version it worked fine and gave what I assume is an array, the members being accessible by `xxx = components[2]` etc.

Comment: After further testing, the archive is not being recognized as an array by the newer code but IS by the deprecated code. With the earlier code I can unarchive as an `NSArray` then cast the members as `SCNNode`'s. The newer method will not load the arrays. I think this method is a dead end and I need another mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way to decode an array of SCNNode is by saying

```
let components = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedArrayOfObjects(ofClass: SCNNode.self, from: moleData)
```

That should work. If it doesn't, you'll have to just keep using the deprecated method; but I think it will.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything of the sort.

Comment: Bummer! I spoke too soon. Works fine on simulator, doesn't work on devices.

Comment: Weird, I don't see how that can be. Something else must be going on.

Comment: The method is failing on the devices, caught in the `guard` `else`, but succeeding on simulator. I don't get it.

Comment: I can't reproduce that, and this isn't something that would reasonably differ from a simulator to a device.

Comment: If you post one of the problematic plist files I can take a look at it.

Comment: You don't post it "here". Just put it somewhere public and tell me where it is.